# How to add a new file association from a plugin

Tags: visual-studio-code

In a project I have some internal files that are just JSON files but with specific well known filenames. I would like to add file associations for these files from my visual studio code plugin so they automatically get recognized as JSON and highlighted accordingly but cannot see a way to do this from the plugin. Does anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you can just add the necessary associations to the workspace settings

```ts
// add file associations for our configurations files
let conf = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('files');
let assocs = conf.get<{}>('associations');
assocs['special.info'] = 'json';
conf.update('associations', assocs, ConfigurationTarget.Workspace);
```